# How to color highlight text in a black/white document easily

Tags: colors, editing

I am editing a 96 chapter book. The text is in normal black letters on a white background. What I want to be able to do is: 
I want to have any changes or additions automatically shown in another (per-selected) color.
Without having to 
a)high lite a word or phrase to be changed or added and then
b)going to the toolbar and clicking on the font color

In other words I want the original color of the text to remain as it is and any additions or changes to be visible in another color without having to use the toolbar.
Can this be done? I use OpenOffice or Word 2007 in Windows 7.

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft Office Word has **Track Changes** (under *Review → Tracking* for Office 2007). You can change the color in *Track Changes ▼ Change Tracking Options*.

LibreOffice has a similar, although slightly less convenient, feature under *Edit → Changes → Record*; the color can be set in *Tools → Options → LibreOffice Writer → Changes*.

Answer (score 2):

OOo writer will write in colour and changed text:

- menu bar -> edit -> changes -> click - record and show

Set colour in:

- tools -> options -> oo writer -> changes -> Insertions

Set colour e.g. blue 4 provides a highlighted style

- set text -> attributes italic, etc.

When set to record it will record all changes.

Shortcut keys for OOo edit:

- <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> (edit) / <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd> (changes) /  <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> (record)(un record) / <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> (show)(un show)
- <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> (accept)

Opens a spell checker style dialog box:

- <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> (accept all) / <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> (reject all) / <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> (accept one) / <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> (reject one)

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I was aware of the “Track changes” facilities in both programs, but after the document has been edited (changed or added to), how do you easily get rid of the left hand side marking (in OOo) and the text underline (which is not a real underline)? In this case I want to be able to quickly accept the changes and additions. 
Example:   
Original text:       ools -> options -> oo writer -> changes -> Insertion
Edited text  :   |  *T*ools -> options -> oo writer -> changes -> Insertion*s* *and deletions*             @grawity

Comment: @Lateron -added to answer, tried it out - ok speed -  hope this help

Comment: To @mic84. Thank you, I will try it out.